# View slope of computed line Avplot function

Tags: r, regression

I'm using the Avplots function in R. The function places a fitted line on the graph, and I'm wondering if there is a way to view the equation of that line. I know I could computationally reproduce it us the lm function, but I'm curious if there is a way to view the "back-end" code being used to produce the graph.

Thanks!

Below is some code. The function takes a linear model followed by the variables you want to create avPlots for (all against the regressor).

```
avPlots(mlm1,terms=~pctUrban+log(ppgdp))
```

Comment: It's from the car package. I edited it to include code. It's not all that helpful, just wondering if someone had some insider info on the package.

Answer (score 1):

I am not very familiar with Added-Variable Plots, but had an idea, though I'm not entirely sure what you are looking for. I hope this might be helpful.

Say you have an example using a linear model `lm` such as this (also from the Car package):

```
res <- avPlots(lm(prestige~income+education+type, data=Duncan))
```

This includes data on the prestige and other characteristics of 45 U. S. occupations in 1950.

The returned data `res` will have the data points for each of the four plots generated (see below). The `avPlot` function uses `lsfit` (least squares fit) for the fitted line. This can also be done from the returned data for each factor (e.g., for `typeprof`):

```
fit <- lsfit(res$typeprof[,1], res$typeprof[,2])
```

You could then get your slope from the `coefficients` (16.7):

```
fit$coefficients
   Intercept            X 
4.178364e-16 1.665751e+01
```

As mentioned, this would give the same slopes from the `lm` model:

```
Call:
lm(formula = prestige ~ income + education + type, data = Duncan)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       income    education     typeprof       typewc  
    -0.1850       0.5975       0.3453      16.6575     -14.6611
```

[image: example added-variable plot]